# Load HTML <select> options while loading the page in php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, html-select

How to load  option dynamically,when we have to load options like eg: 1-500. as the values in select list.

Loding can be either done in php or javascript.
plz can someone provide eg/simple snippet or helpfull links? Thanks!

I tried: Javascript

```
for(var i=1;i<=500;i++)
{
    //create new option
    var option = new Option(i, "Value" + i);
    //Add the new option it to the select
    sel.options[i] = option;
}
```

Comment: If you have the values server-side in your PHP code then you'd simply add `option` elements to the rendered output in a loop over those values.  Have you made any attempt at this?

Comment: can you post any sample code that you've already written for this ?

Comment: @David: It looks like the OP wants to not have them statically generated, but rather to have them loaded separately from the page.

Comment: @zebediah49: Well, "static" and "dynamic" are relative terms.  The OP did indicate that the loading "can be done in PHP".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the values with a foreach, for or while loop, and just ouput whatever you need:

```
<?php

    $html = '<select>';

    for ($i=0; $i<500; $i++) {
        $html .= '<option value="' . $i . '">Option ' . $i . '</option>';
    }

    $html .= '</select>';

    echo $html;

?>
```